# Issues with redis-rails and connection_pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, connection-pool, redis-rails

How I can initialize my redis_store to have connection pooling. I want to add pooling attributes { pool_size: 10, pool_timeout: 10 } I have added connection_pool gem

```
Example::Application.config.session_store :redis_store,
                                      servers: { host:      'localhost',
                                                 port:      6379,
                                                 db:        0,
                                                 namespace: 'session'
                                      },
                                      expires_in: 25.hours,
```

It gives error on server boot. If I add something like below;

```
Example::Application.config.session_store :redis_store,
                                      servers: { host:      'localhost',
                                                 port:      6379,
                                                 db:        0,
                                                 namespace: 'session'
                                      },
                                      expires_in: 25.hours,
                                      { pool_size: 10, pool_timeout: 10 }
```

Comment: What error you're receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I'd executed your code, I've run into a simple `SyntaxError`. Might be your problem, since the correct specifying of the options should be:

```
Example::Application.config.session_store :redis_store,
                                      servers: { host:      'localhost',
                                                 port:      6379,
                                                 db:        0,
                                                 namespace: 'session'
                                      },
                                      expires_in: 25.hours,
                                      pool_size: 10,
                                      pool_timeout: 10
```